# Current Division Rule

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, current-divider, circuit-theory

I have the following circuit.They are simplifying the circuit and applying 
current division

[image]

To use current division the incoming current should not have a resistor in between,right?

But in this case  1A first passes through 1 ohm resistor before entering the //circuit.In such case can the total current be taken as 1A for using in the current division equation?

Comment: The simplification is because the 3 ohm resistor is shorted out.

Comment: We know we have 1A in the 1st 1 ohm resistor and the 3 ohm resistor is shorted out so this simplifies to how does 1 amp share between a 1 ohm and a 2 ohm parallel connection.

Comment: What are you actually trying to calculate?

Comment: @Andyaka I understand that .. i need to know how current division can be applied since the current first go through 1 ohm resistor.

Comment: Changing the value of the first 1 ohm resistor makes no difference to the current in any other resistor since we know it has 1 amp flowing through it.  It only makes a difference to the voltage across it and the voltage across the current source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What (current) goes into the node must come out. (kirchoff's law)

The 1A passes through the first 1 Ohm resistor. At the other side we still have 1 Amp (although it will drop 1V across that resistor) going into the other two resistors in parallel.

This is then divided between the 1 Ohm and 2 Ohm resistor.

The large resistor will take LESS current. In this case the 2 Ohm resistor will take 1/3 rd A and the 1 Ohm will take 2/3 Amp.

Another way of looking at it.

The 1 and 2 Ohms are in parallel so we can calculate the single equivalant resistance, R:

```
  1/R     =   1/1  + 1/2

    R     =   2/3 Ohm
```

Using Ohm's law the voltage across this resistance will be

```
    V   =     I R    =   1 x 2/3     =   2/3V
```

Now 2/3V across the 1 Ohm produces a current of 2/3 A

and 2/3V across the 2 Ohm resistor produces   1/3A

Comment: Thanks.. so if im asked to find out the current that is going through the 2 ohm resistor, will the 2 ohm and 1 ohm resistor have the same values of voltage?so that ohms law can be applied... how do you say that these 2 resistances have the same voltage across them? If im asked to find the current through 1ohm(the one in series with 2 and 1 equivalent)..how should i proceed.

Comment: @elecman The 2 Ohms and 1 ohm will have the same voltage across them because they are connected in parallel. The 1 amp current will be divided between them (imagine a river splitting into two branches and then coming back together).  To calculate the equivalent resistance (R) of the two branches we use the parallel resistance formula  -  1/R  = 1/R1 +  1/R2.  From there you can do a simple Ohm's Law calculation to work out the voltage drop @ 1A (= 2/3V), then use Ohm's law again to work out the current in the 1 Ohm resistor (I = V/R =2/3 A)